# Hibernate, найти строчку в таблице на которую нет ссылок

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Предположим есть таблица File с полями id, fileName, на нее могут ссылаться многие другие объекты системы. Можно ли штатными средствами Hibernate найти все сущности на которые никто не ссылается? Либо хотябы все ссылки на эту сущность?

P.S. Использую Spring Data поверх Hibernate, если это как-то поможет.

Comment: Только поочерёдная проверка ассоциаций с другими типами сущностей поможет найти сущности, на которые никто не ссылается. В зависимости от типа ассоциации (многие-к-одному, один-ко-многим и пр.) проверка выполняется по разному.

Answer (score 1):

Данную проблему в своем случае решил путем задания двухсторонних связей. В одном классе (зависимом) -

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "avatar")
private Set<Users> users;
```

В ссылающемся:

```
@JoinColumn
@ManyToOne
private File avatar;
```

Таким образом структура базы данных не изменяется, но можно проверить связи.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, но для этого явно указывать связи между таблицами как в бд так и в hibernate.

Тогда при генерации классов-представлений в них будут объявлены то ли Set, то ли List - списки с объектами зависимых строк из других таблиц.

**PS В обще там есть Restriction.isEmpty() для колекций, но явных примеров, как указать на коллекцию зависимых строк, я не нашел. Тестить надо.**

Comment: Во-первых, Вы не ответили на вопрос (написали "_Можно_", но не написали как именно). Во-вторых, думаю что автор подразумевал поиск конкретных записей в таблице БД, а не инспекцию структуры данных.

Comment: Я лишь пояснил что ВПРИНЦИПЕ, такое возможно, одно но, только перебором. Как объявлять связи таблиц я не буду объяснять, т.к. это отдельная и мохнатая тема (темпаче зависит от способа мапинга). PS В обще там есть Restriction.isEmpty() для колекций, но явных примеров, как указать на коллекцию зависимых строк, я не нашел. Тестить надо.

Answer (score 0):

Штатных средств в `Hibernate` для этого нет. Вам следует написать `SQL`-запрос, который осуществит выборку из **всех** ссылающихся таблиц. В вопросе не представлена структура БД, поэтому попробую привести абстрактный пример подобного запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM File WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT file_id FROM table1
  UNION SELECT file_id FROM table2
  UNION ...
)
```

Выполнить запрос можно с помощью `javax.persistence.EntityManager.createNativeQuery` или `org.hibernate.Session.createSQLQuery`, в зависимости от того, какое API используете.
Такой запрос может оказаться очень ресурсоёмким, поэтому следует провести тесты производительности, анализ запроса.

Если не получится достигнуть желаемой производительности/скорости выполнения, оформите по этому поводу новый вопрос с описанием структуры таблиц, оформив его тегами, относящимися к SQL, а не к Hibernate, и обязательно укажите какая СУБД используется (в тегах тоже).